# Automatically Renew Provisioning Profiles

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, auto-renewing

Is there a way to automatically renew Provisioning Profiles before they expire? I am open to any solution, whether it is with OS X Server, third party service, command line tools, scripts, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no way to do it.